# Magento - No Edit Order Address Link

Tags: magento

I used to have an 'Edit' link above the shipping and billing address when I viewed an order in Magento 1.6.1.0 which allowed me to make updates to the addresses.

I just went to edit an address today and noticed the links are no longer there. Does anyone know what could have happened to these or which file I should be looking in for problems?

Comment: show us your **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml** and **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php** files

Comment: and if possible, do you remember what was the last thing you did before the edit link go away (which module did you installed?..)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause of the problem. It was this extension:
http://www.fmeextensions.com/one-step-checkout.html

After disabling it the links reappeared.

Comment: It is disconcerting to me that a one step checkout breaks something in adminhtml. Do they have any files install to `app/design/adminhtml`?

Comment: yes they have a file in public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/quickcheckout/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml. Possibly to show customer comments in the back end.

Comment: Then it was that file which likely broke your admin login. :)